# Hystrix Fallback method execution

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, circuit-breaker

Below is my Hystrix command configuration:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fall", commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "5"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "10000") })
    public <T> T getInfo(Class clazz) {....}
```

Fallback method:

```
public <T> T fall(Class clazz) {
        System.out.println("fallback");
        throw new CustomRuntimeException("API Down"); 
    }
```

I understand that as per the below configuration i.e.

```
@HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "5"),
@HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "10000") }
```

5 request would be allowed in 10s until the circuit trips open and every request from 5th request would be rejected and as i am throwing an exception in the fallback method it would be wrapped as `HystrixRuntimeException`.

But i am facing below issue:

- Until the circuit trips open the fallback is executing normally and
  throwing `CustomRuntimeException` (Note: Hystrix Command method also
  throws `CustomRuntimeException` )
- After the circuit trips open i getting `Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getInfo short-circuited and fallback failed.`

**Question**:

1. **Why the exception is not wrapped as HystrixRuntimeException before the circuit is open i.e. Currently the fallback is executed normally and throws CustomRuntimeException until the circuit gets open?***

[image: How Hystrix works]

2. ***Why in flow 1->2->3->4->5->6->8 the fallback method is executed even after
   failing (i.e. Throwing `CustomRuntimeException`) and does not throws
   a wrapped `HystrixRuntimeException`, which is happening in the case of flow
   1->2->3->4->8 and 1->2->3->5->8***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the Hystrix Javanica documentation for the exception handling: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#error-propagation

Quoting from the docs:

"It is worth noting that by default a caller will always get the root cause exception ... never HystrixBadRequestException or HystrixRuntimeException"

"If command has a fallback then only first exception that triggers fallback logic will be propagated to caller."

These two quotes answer your first question: the exception from the first method will be the exception thrown, not the HystrixRuntimeException. The exception thrown in the fallback will never be shown.

When the circuit breaker is open, a RuntimeException will be thrown. Again, the exception thrown in the fallback will never be shown.

I wrote a test case for this: https://github.com/ahus1/hystrix-spring-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/de/ahus1/hystrixspring/HystrixExceptionHandlingInSpring.java

Side notes:

1. you added the configuration for your cicruit breaker to the code. They are usually better placed in the spring configuration with their full name: `hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold`.
2. The requestVolumeThreshold works a bit differently from what you described: it defines the minimum number of requests that are necessary in a time window before the cicruit breaker is allowed to trigger. The errorThresholdPercentage is the percentage of errors that are allowed once the minimum number of requests (5 in your case) has been reached. In your case 5 out of 5 calls failed, that is 100%. 100% is greater than 50% (default value for the circuit breaker), therefore it opens.

Comment: Actually i am throwing 2 different exceptions;one in command method and other one in fallback method respectively. Technically it should show only the root cause of failure i.e. Exception thrown by Command method; but in my case i am getting only the exception thrown by the fallback.

Comment: I've update the answer with a link to a example project. In this example I always receive the primary exception when the circuit breaker is closed, and a RuntimeException when the circuit breaker is open.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.
The test cases are working fine with Camden.SR7 (hystrix version 1.5.6) but not in Dalston.SR3 (hystrix version 1.5.12).After the version update,it is propagating the exception thrown from fallback method.I think the error propagation of command method after hiding the fallback exception was an issue and was fixed reference:https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/332.

Comment: As per the flow chart mentioned in the above link, the fallback exception has to wrapped as HystrixRuntimeException but his is not happening.
I've created a project on the same and have also mentioned my issues as comments in it.
https://github.com/chrysalisDVT/hystrix-example

Could you please take a look at the same? 
It would of great help to get your thoughts on the comments in the project.

Comment: I see in the release notes of 1.5.7 that the behavior changed: "Javanica: Send fallback exception to client instead of primary command.". There is a link to the Pull request, and this links to https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1344 with some comments at the end. By default Javanica (the annotation in Spring) should never return a HystrixRuntimeException. HystrixRuntimeExceptions if you use it without Spring. I think you are on the right track - good luck! I'm out of this discussion.